# Using groovy in Java EE Apps?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, groovy

Did anyone yet use Groovy in Java EE Web Applications? Is it worth digging deeper into this and would I benefit from it using when using Java EE, JSF, Facelets etc?

What I especially looking for would be things like Groovy auto-generates getter/setter, or not having to always use `object.getProperty` but just writing conduits like `object.list.property.prop` and so on.

Is it worth it?

Comment: The getter/setter generation should not be the deciding factor.  Any decent IDE, like IntelliJ, can manage that for you.

Comment: Yes, I know eclipse can generate getsetters. I mean that things like these do not even thow up in the code, but are only generated at compiler time.

Comment: That shouldn't be a deciding factor in using a technology, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [Grails](http://grails.org/), if you're interested in Groovy for web apps.  This is basically Groovy atop a Spring MVC/Hibernate/Sitemesh framework.

Development can be quicker, with the more efficient syntax,  convention-based setup, scaffolding, and there are a lot of plugins to add functionality.  But, maintenance may be challenging in a complex app, and when something goes wrong in all the magic it works to hide implementation from you, it can be painful to debug.